# History of ' low-dimensional geometry '

Tags: math-history, low-dimensional-topology

I want to have a brief history about the  low-dimensional manifolds and geometric structures on manifolds specially on low-dimensional manifolds .where I can read about thus ?

Comment: Here is an essay from Milnor: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/milnhist.pdf

It only goes back to the 50s, but I found it quite interesting.

Comment: In the 1980's, people started using ideas from physics to study the topology of $3$- and $4$-manifolds. See the following article of Atiyah for the early history of mathematical gauge theory: https://web.math.princeton.edu/~lewallen/AtiyahFloer.pdf